# I get "sqs-main.rb:42:in `<module:SqsTest>': undefined method `purge' for SqsTest:Module (NoMethodError)" , in Ruby

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, amazon-sqs, ruby-module

My code:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

module SqsTest

    access_key_id = $access_key_id
secret_access_key=$secret_access_key
session_token = $session_token 

    sqs_client = Aws::SQS::Client.new(
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials:Aws::Credentials.new(access_key_id, secret_access_key,session_token )
      )
   
queue_url = sqs_client.get_queue_url(queue_name: 'test-queue').queue_url
# puts queue_url


def purge(options = {})
  options = options.merge(queue_url: '{here is the queue link}')
  resp = Aws::Plugins::UserAgent.feature('resource') do
    sqs_client.purge_queue(options)
  end
  resp.data

end

purge

end
```

I had learned that to call a method with ruby ​​you just need to invoke the method name, and normally that works for me, but apparently inside a module it doesn't. I wanted to understand why and if anyone knows how to invoke the method in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I called the module name before the method name, like this:

```
def SqsTest.purge
```

and then it worked.

```
def SqsTest.purge(options = {})
  options = options.merge(queue_url: '{here is the queue link}')
  resp = Aws::Plugins::UserAgent.feature('resource') do
    $sqs_client.purge_queue(options)
  end
  resp.data

end


purge
```